# Upgrade to Spring Boot 2.1.2 from 2.0.6 causes repository errors

Tags: spring-boot

I tried to upgrade a working application from Spring Boot 2.0.6 to 2.1.2.  I had some troubles with tests after this change, but eventually got around that.  I can successfully build the application from NetBeans (`mvn clean install`).  However, when I try to run from a command line using `mvn spring-boot:run`, here is what I get:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> The bean 'xxxRepository', defined in null, could not be
>   registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and
>   overriding is disabled.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting
>   spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

The interesting part is that every time I try to run it, the error is on a different repository, but always with the same message.

It would seem that this has to do with [this change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-booT/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding):

> Bean Overriding
>
> Bean overriding has been disabled by default to prevent a bean being
>   accidentally overridden. If you are relying on overriding, you will
>   need to set spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding to true.

Given that it is apparently effecting all my repositories, my guess is that there is a configuration problem somewhere.  I can follow the recommended action, **but it actually made no difference**.  The problem is that I don't know what to change in the configuration to get this working again.  I'm not even sure what to post that is pertinent to the issue.  Any ideas on how to figure this out?

Comment: If you drop back to Spring Boot 2.0.6, you should see info level log messages informing you of the beans that are being overridden and, hopefully, shedding some light on why that's happening.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I did a search on the logs, and there was nothing on the INFO level regarding any beans being overridden.  I next did a search for "overrid" and it found `2019-02-05 14:55:27,765 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG spi.ServiceBinding - Overriding existing service binding [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccService]`, which doesn't seem like something I have control over.  I next did a search for "bean", but that didn't produce anything that looked promising.  Any other ideas what to search for, or is this a good indication that nothing is actually being overridden?

Comment: I have a similar problem currently, but it occurs only when i add a spring property as a program argument in my IDE, no idea how to solve it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We ran into this issue upgrading from Spring Boot 2.0.x to 2.1.x.

I could "solve" this issue by allowing bean definition override with `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding: true` but it felt like hiding the root cause.
In fact bean definition overriding used to hide poor configuration on our side.

After inspecting our `@Configuration` classes we were **scanning packages containing our repositories twice**, using `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableJpaRepository` on the same packages from different classes : once with filters `@ComponentScan.Filter`, once without.

Removing the second component scan fixed the issue.

Comment: After I cleared my maven repository, the program was working, so something funny had happened there.  I later discovered that I still had allow-bean-definition-overriding set to true, which was now allowing my program to work.  Removing that caused an error.  Thanks to your answer, I found that I had `@EnableJpaRepository` set in two places.  Removing one allowed me to remove the bean-definition-overriding and still have a working application.  Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know if this property of marking bean-overriding true is going to be there for long time in future OR would it be deprecated and later removed in the near future?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this error before and i had a class BOTH annotated with @Component or @Repository or @Service AND also registered as a @Bean in a config class.  Is that your case also by any chance?

Comment: In my `WebSecurityConfig` class, I had a Bean that was overriding UserDetailsService with my own implementation.  I renamed the bean to make sure there was no name conflicts, but that did not help.  I didn't find any cases like you mentioned, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: the "defined in null" part bothers me, can you show us some code to see how everything is wired?

Comment: What code would be the most helpful to see?  I'm not sure what to post.

Comment: The issue is definitely linked to registering the same bean twice, the fact that Spring would register twice a class annotated with two different stereotypes looks like a problem from Spring ?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem, but it was only with `@NotNull` annotation. When I upgraded the spring it stopped to work. I tried a lot of things that  I found here in SO, but the only thing that worked to me was to eliminate the database and run spring again. I know that it sucks, but didn't find another solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "eliminate the database"?

Comment: If by "eliminate the database" you were referring to the maven repository, then I think that is what did the trick.  I'm not sure exactly what the problem was, but there must have been something conflicting somewhere that was causing an issue.  It is running now, though.  Thanks!

Comment: "Eliminating the database" is not a solution to a repository problem